# Trouble downloading and accessing zip files from API in R

Tags: r, json, api, zip

I am trying to automate a process in R which involves downloading a zipped folder from an API* which contains a few .csv/.xml files, accessing its contents, and then extracting the .csv/.xml that I actually care about into a dataframe (or something else that is workable). However, I am having some problems accessing the contents of the API pull. From what I gather, the proper process for pulling from an API is to use `GET()` from the `httr` package to access the API's files, then the `jsonlite` package to process it. The second step in this process is failing me. The code I have been trying to use is roughly as follows:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

req <- "http://request.path.com/thisisanapi/SingleZip?option1=yes&option2=no"
res <- GET(url = req)
#this works as expected, with res$status_code == 200

#OPTION 1:
api_char <- rawToChar(res$content)
api_call <- fromJSON(api_char, flatten=T)

#OPTION 2:
api_char2 <- content(res, "text")
api_call2 <- fromJSON(api_char2, flatten=T)
```

In option 1, the first line fails with an "embedded nul in string" error. In option 2, the second line fails with a "lexical error: invalid char in json text" error.

I did some reading and found a few related threads. First, [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491173/how-to-download-and-or-extract-data-stored-in-a-raw-binary-zip-object-within-a?newreg=36be0800c08b4a34b8663bf013de4745) looks to be doing a very similar thing to me, but did not experience this error (this suggests that maybe the files are zipped/stored differently between the APIs that the two of us are using and that I have set up the `GET()` incorrectly?). Second, [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447883/embedded-nul-in-string-importing-raw-data-of-content-type-text-tab-separated-va) seems to be experiencing a similar problem with converting the raw data from the API. I attempted the fix from this thread, but it did not work. In option 1, the first line ran but the second line gave a similar "lexical error: invalid char in json text" as in option before and, in option 2, the second line gave a "if (is.character(txt) && length(txt) == 1 && nchar(txt, type = "bytes") <  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error, which I am not quite sure how to interpret. This may be because the `content_type` differs between our API pulls: mine is `application/x-zip-compressed` and theirs is `text/tab-separated-values; charset=utf-16le`, so maybe removing the null characters is altogether inappropriate here.

There is some documentation on usage of the API I am using*, but a lot of it is a few years old now and seems to focus more on manual usage rather than integration with large automated downloads like I am working on (my end goal is a loop which executes the process described many times over slightly varying urls). I am most certainly a beginner to using APIs like this, and would really appreciate some insight!

* = specifically, I am pulling from CAISO's OASIS API. If you want to follow along with some real files, replace `"http://request.path.com/thisisanapi/SingleZip?option1=yes&option2=no"` with `"http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?resultformat=6&queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&version=3&startdatetime=20201225T09:00-0000&enddatetime=20201226T9:10-0000&market_run_id=RTM&grp_type=ALL"`

Comment: Andrew, did my answer below help you? You haven't acknowledged or responded to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue here is that you don't have a JSON return from the API. You have a .zip file being returned, as binary (I think?) data. Your challenge is to process that data. I don't think `fromJSON()` will help you, as the data from the API isn't in JSON format.

Here's how I would do it. I prefer to use the `httr2` package. The process below makes it nice and clear what the parameters of the query are.

```r
library(httr2)

req <- httr2::request("http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi")

query <- req %>% 
  httr2::req_url_path_append("SingleZip") %>% 
  httr2::req_url_query(resultformat = 6) %>% 
  httr2::req_url_query(queryname = "PRC_INTVL_LMP") %>% 
  httr2::req_url_query(version = 3) %>% 
  httr2::req_url_query(startdatetime = "20201225T09:00-0000") %>% 
  httr2::req_url_query(enddatetime = "20201226T9:10-0000") %>% 
  httr2::req_url_query(market_run_id = "RTM") %>% 
  httr2::req_url_query(grp_type = "ALL")

# Check what our query looks like
query
#> <httr2_request>
#> GET
#> http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?resultformat=6&queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&version=3&startdatetime=20201225T09%3A00-0000&enddatetime=20201226T9%3A10-0000&market_run_id=RTM&grp_type=ALL
#> Body: empty

resp <- query %>% 
  httr2::req_perform()

# Check what content type and encoding we have
# All looks good
resp %>% 
  httr2::resp_content_type()
#> [1] "application/x-zip-compressed"
resp %>% 
  httr2::resp_encoding()
#> [1] "UTF-8"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Then you have a choice what to do, if you want to write the data to a zip file.

I discovered that the `brio` package will write raw data to a file nicely. Or you can just use `download.file` to download the .zip from the URL (you can just do that without all the httr stuff above). You need to use `mode = "wb"`.

```r
resp %>% 
  httr2::resp_body_raw() %>% 
  brio::write_file_raw(path = "out.zip")

# alternative using your original URL or query$url

download.file(query$url, "out.zip", mode = "wb")
```

Answer (score 0):

Oasis returns a zipped file. One method is to unzip the contents to a temporary file and then either read in that file to a dataframe or save to a local directory.

```
  # Unzip file to data frame, assumes CSV content requested
  temp_file <- tempfile() # create temporary file
  writeBin(content(resp), temp_file) # unzip CSV results to temporary file
  df <- read_csv(temp_file) # read in temporary csv file to dataframe
  file.remove(temp_file) # remove temporary file


  # Unzip file and save to folder ####
  temp_file <- tempfile() # create temp file
  writeBin(content(resp), temp_file) # write contents of response to temp file
  unzip(temp_file, exdir = save_to_folder) # unzip contents to folder
  file.remove(temp_file) # remove temporary file
```